# How to create asymetric matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I need to create this construction.

[image]

And I wrote this code

```
    \begin{equation*}
      b_{12}^{(2)} =  
       \begin{array}{ccccccc}
        1 & a & b & c & d &  & \\
        a & 1 & \overline{e} & 0 & \overline{f} & & \\
        \cline{1-5}
        \vspace{-2ex} &&&&&& \\
        a+ & a+ & b\overline{e}+ & 0+ & d\overline{f} & = &
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
```

[image]

This is not nice. Please help. Thanks

Comment: What is "not nice" about it? Is there some logic behind the "matrix addition"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some hand formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2]{%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  #1\\#2
  \end{array}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r<{{}} *{9}{>{{}}c<{{}}} }
b_{12}^{(2)} = &
  \splitcell{1}{a} &&
  \splitcell{a}{1} &&
  \splitcell{b}{\bar{e}} &&
  \splitcell{c}{0} &&
  \splitcell{d}{\bar{f}} \\
\cmidrule{2-10}
& a & + & a & + & b\bar{e} & + & 0 & + & d\bar{f}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to an environment to test it at the moment, but this *should* work, I think: you can use the `amsmath` package's `\genfrac` command to stack two expressions with a line between them.

```
\genfrac{}{}{}{}{%
 \begin{matrix}
  1 & a & b & c & d\\
  a & 1 & \bar{e} & 0 & \bar{f}
 \end{matrix}%
}{a + a + b\bar{e} + 0 + d\bar{f}}
```

This will automatically produce the proper spacing.

Comment: This is work, but in down string is small font